# CFD: Mesh problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mesh, ansys-fluent

I wish to study the 2D heat transfer of the soda can using Fluent. For my geometry I took a circle. 
My problem while meshing the circle; Because i need to mesh it from inside.
I used the mapped faced meshing then I used the edge sizing for the edge of the circle with no bias and then I sized the line that I create.
[I tried to create 1 vertical line (Edge to Edge) and size it using this bias
 ----- --- - --- ----- ]
But the mesh was not very symmetric and didn't have circular shape.
I tried put a second horizontal line and size using the correct bias type and factor but also didn't get what I want.

So I want a good mesh inside a circle in 2D (Not pipe in 3D)

NB: please as a beginner in fluent I wish to have a step by step procedure to follow

Comment: This is a question best asked on a Fluent-specific forum.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Wolfgang is right, this question is software-specific (for example, only users of FLUENT would know what "mapped faced meshing" means"), so you'd  have better chances at, e.g., [CFD-Online's FLUENT forum](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/fluent/).

Answer (score 3):

Go for a 5 block structured O-type mesh:

[image]